# Get original text/value of editable <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with some editable cells/.  I can get the updated value and save the changes with no problem.  A part of my site is to track the change history, so I need to know if there is anything with Javascript or JQuery to get the original value of the cell/, from when the page was originally loaded.  (Something comparable to .defaultValue for inputs would be nice.)

I've been looking around, but haven't found anything that can really do this.

Thanks,
Chad

Comment: You can read and store the values via JavaScript right after the page got loaded.

Comment: There's nothing that can do this, only manually storing initial values somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `data` attribute for this. Basic example here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="example" data-init="This is the initial content.">This is the initial content.</div>
  <button id="show" type="button">Click here to show the initial content</button>
<script>
  var exampleDIV = document.getElementById('example'),
      showBUTTON = document.getElementById('show');

  // change the content of the element
  exampleDIV.innerHTML = 'The content has been changed.';

  // get the initial content
  showBUTTON.addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert(exampleDIV.getAttribute('data-init'));
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/yujivusihu/1/edit?html,output).

### Update

If you would like to insert the data attributes with JavaScript, you can use this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<table id="sample">
  <tr>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 01</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 02</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 03</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 04</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 05</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 06</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 07</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 08</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 09</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 10</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 11</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Initial Value 12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
Cell #<input id="cellno" name="cellno" type="number" min="1" max="12" value="1">
<button type="button" id="show">Show Initial Value</button>
<script>
  var sampleTABLE = document.getElementById('sample'),
      showBUTTON = document.getElementById('show'),
      cellnoINPUT = document.getElementById('cellno'),
      cellsTD = sampleTABLE.getElementsByTagName('td');

  // store all values in data attributes
  for(var i=0,l=cellsTD.length;i<l;i++){
    cellsTD[i].setAttribute('data-init',cellsTD[i].innerHTML);
  }

  // get the initial content
  showBUTTON.addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert(cellsTD[cellnoINPUT.value - 1].getAttribute('data-init'));
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Example [here](http://jsbin.com/wayogomiji/2/edit?html,output).